# react component lifecycle to execute before render

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to have some check before react component is rendered..

Lets say I have a component which renders something like

```jsx
render() {
    const {videos, actions} = this.props

    return (
        <div>
            <List />
        </div>
    )
}
```

But before rendering the list I want to have custom check on the list... 
What I meant to say is before showing the `<List />` component I want to have some check and only after that check is finished I want to show the component with render method ..

The check I am mentioning here might be anything like the list should be 10 in count or anything.

I have tried following

```jsx
componentWillUpdate(){
    console.log("Component will update")
}

shouldComponentUpdate(){
    console.log("Should component update")
}
```

From the react documentation I knew that both of them are called before render... But when I do this nothing is printed in the console but `render` method is called..

I know that `componentWillMount()` is called before render but what I want is a function which calls render only after the completion or return from the function

Hope you understand and need help

Comment: Why not just call that function in `render()` itself, before returning your elements?

Comment: did you try anything from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the render() function you can run checks before you return the JSX/elements:

```
render() {
  // run any checks here
  const {videos, actions} = this.props

    return (
    <div>
        <List />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what if that call is async

Comment: if the call is async, you'll need to handle the get request in, componentDidMount like so:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

You can return early from render with a different result. When the props change, render will be called again with newer props.

```
class MyComponent {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    if (items.length < 10) return <span>Loading...</span>;

    return <List items={items} />;
  }
}
```